# How to get Vlan ID details when a new VLAN order is placed in IBM Cloud using softlayer REST API

Tags: rest, api, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have placed a new VLAN order in the IBM Cloud. As a response I have the "order ID". Using the order ID I need to get the VLAN ID details.

Please let me know whether there are any REST API references to get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following example:

Method GET

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[billingItem[id,orderItem[id,order[id]]]]&objectFilter={"networkVlans": {"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"id":{"operation": 999999}}}}}}
```

the 999999 change with your order ID